# Save console messages for debugging in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

How can I get all console messages on nightwatch.js debugging?

At phantom it's possible to use `page.onError` handler. Can I do the same with nightwatch?

I know about `window.onerror` but is there way to save all console messages?

Can anyone share working config / code ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Solution:

```
module.exports = {
  'Check getting log messages' : function (client) {
    client
      .url('http://jsbin.com/rohilugegi/1/')
      .getLogTypes(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .getLog('browser', function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      })
    ;

    return client;
  },
```

It will give output

> ```
> [Start] Test Suite
> ==================
>
> Running:  Check getting log messages
> [ 'har', 'browser', 'client', 'server' ]
> [ { message: 'Test error\n  error (:0)',
>     timestamp: 1428447687315,
>     level: 'WARNING' },
>   { message: 'Test log (:)',
>     timestamp: 1428447687315,
>     level: 'INFO' } ]
> No assertions ran.
> ```

Commands **getLogTypes** and **getLog** are already implemented at [client commands](https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/blob/master/lib/api/client-commands.js) but their description are absent at site API

Looks like it worth read source code instead of documentation

Below jsdoc for this functions from source code :

````
/**
 * Gets the available log types
 *
 * ```
 * this.demoTest = function(client) {
 *   this.getLogTypes(function( typesArray ) {
 *     
 *   });
 * };
 * ```
 *
 * @method getLogTypes
 * @param {function} [callback] Optional callback function to be called when the command finishes.
 * @api commands
 * @see logTypes
 */
````

and

````
/**
 * Gets a log from selenium
 *
 * ```
 * this.demoTest = function(client) {
 *   this.getLog( 'browser', function( logEntriesArray ) {
 *     console.log( "Log length: " + logEntriesArray.length );
 *     logEntriesArray.forEach( function( log ) {
 *        console.log( "[" + log.level + "] " + log.timestamp + " : " + log.message );
 *      } );
 *   });
 * };
 * ```
 *
 * @method getLog
 * @param {string} typeString Log type to request
 * @param {function} [callback] Optional callback function to be called when the command finishes.
 * @api commands
 * @see log
 */
````

Comment: I'm getting an empty log using this technique with Chrome.  Which browser are you using?  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This bin was created anonymously and its free preview time has expired  - just create another one for test

Comment: The bin seems fine and I see the console log manually.  I'm using the Dockerized Selenium server with Chrome and wonder if I have to tell it to turn on logging some how.

Comment: I no longer remember, sorry.

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk - in your example results, you show a log with level "INFO".  I can get errors to show this way (using console.error()), but I can't see anything logged with console.log().  How did you get it to show INFO messages for you?  Do you know what client-side code you used?

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk no console.log is displayed.

Comment: @bier hier You have to set the loggingPrefs on the selenium web driver desiredCapabilities otherwise it will not show them. See my answer below.

Comment: Any idea how to make it work in **Firefox** (geckodriver)?

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you set *loggingPrefs* to { 'browser' : 'ALL' } in your nightwatch configuration otherwise you won't see entries in the browser console that were written with console.log.
My nightwatch.conf.js looks something like:

```
            desiredCapabilities: {
              browserName: 'chrome',
              handlesAlerts: true,
              loggingPrefs: { 'browser': 'ALL' }
            }
```

Next, like the others have said you just have to use the built-in *getLog* function on the client.
e.g.

```
   browser.getLog('browser', function(logEntriesArray) {
      console.log('Log length: ' + logEntriesArray.length);
        logEntriesArray.forEach(function(log) {
            console.log('[' + log.level + '] ' + log.timestamp + ' : ' + log.message);
        });
    });
```